# How to set up blogdown / Travis-CI to ignore certain files?

Tags: r, travis-ci, blogdown

I have a blog written in `blogdown` and deployed via Travis CI.

This means that every time I make a change to a single post the whole site is regenerated. This takes about 10 minutes, so time is not an issue.

One of my posts however calls an exotic API, which sometimes gives unexpected results causing the whole build to crash. This happens even when there has been no change in the offending post.

Is there an option to deploy only changed content and / or specify that the one post should be ignored from the whole site rebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been warned agaist building your website on Travis in [Section 3.4](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/travis-github.html) of the **blogdown** book. I don't think it is a good idea to use this approach unless your website does not contain Rmd posts. If you want to ignore a certain post, you may use a different filename extension (i.e. not `.Rmd`); please see [Section 1.5](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html) for details (scroll to the bottom if you do not have the patience to read the full section).

Comment: You are right, I have willfully decided  - after reading *the* blogdown book, and deciding to ignore your advice - that while Travis has both upsides and downsides the downsides are manageable and the upsides are worth the hassle. The downsides seem to have grown as the complexity of packages I use increased, but this is the first real crisis that I face. I may have to reconsider your advice... It seems sounder now that a couple months ago